# unable to update scikit-learn to version 0.20

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda, conda

I am trying to update sklearn from 0.19.2 to 0.20 by running

```
conda update scikit-learn
```

in the anaconda prompt, but it does not update the package...
I get

```
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

I also tried

```
conda update conda
```

and then again `conda update scikit-learn` but I also get (for both updates)

```
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

if I check sklearn version I still get

```
import sklearn
sklearn.__version__

 '0.19.2'
```

If I type `conda info` I get

```
     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\xxx\.condarc
 populated config files :
          conda version : 4.5.11
    conda-build version : 3.10.5
         python version : 3.6.5.final.0
       base environment : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
                          C:\Users\xxx\.conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.5.11 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.5 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17134
          administrator : True
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

If I try to install sklearn 0.20.0

```
conda install scikit-learn=0.20.0
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - scikit-learn=0.20.0


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    scikit-learn-0.20.0        |   py36heebcf9a_1         5.2 MB

The following packages will be REMOVED:

    imbalanced-learn: 0.3.3-py_0            conda-forge

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    scikit-learn:     0.19.2-py36heebcf9a_0             --> 0.20.0-py36heebcf9a_1

Proceed ([y]/n)? n
```

I get that sklearn is trying to remove a package (imbalanced-learn) that I use..

Should I uninstall and reinstall?

Comment: What response do you get?

Comment: try `conda update conda` before

Comment: @JoshFriedlander I get # All requested packages already installed.

Comment: @Curcuma_ I tried...same story... all the packages already installed

Comment: Are you checking the scikit-learn version in the same environment?

Comment: @VivekKumar  think so...from the same anaconda prompt I start python and then check sklearn..is there a way to double check?

Comment: Looks like you are on windows. I dont have experience with windows but what does `"conda info"` prints for the active environment?

Comment: @VivekKumar I updated my question with the output you requested

Comment: Ok. Maybe conda is not allowing you to update the scikit-learn because any certain other libraries depend on older versions and have not updated the dependencies yet. In this case, try `conda install scikit-learn=0.20.0`. But dont it, press '`n`' after seeing what the conda wants to update or remove along with `scikit-learn`.

Comment: If anything shows up in "to be REMOVED" packages, make sure that is not something which can break the anaconda installation, like conda, anaconda, spyder etc. In the case that happens, make a new environment and try `conda install scikit-learn=0.20.0 --no-deps`. `--no-deps` will not touch your other installed libraries but if there are anything structural or major changes in scikit-learn, then those libraries may throw errors. See the user guide for [more details](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)

Comment: @VivekKumar it's trying to remove only imbalanced-learn (please see updated question) should I proceed and try to reinstall the removed package? should I unistall first sklearn or it is done automatically?

Comment: Yes. Go ahead and press `y` on the previous command (to update scikit-learn, imbalanced-learn will be removed), and then install `imbalanced-learn` again using `conda install -c conda-forge imbalanced-learn`

Comment: pip install -U scikit-learn, this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

It seems that **imbalanced-learn** requires a specific version of **scikit-learn**. If you want to upgrade sklearn to latest version, you may have to remove **imbalanced-learn**.

**Suggestion:**

I would suggest to work with [python-virtualenv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) which allow create separate environment for python projects and handle package dependencies without impacting main system .

Answer (score 0):

`scikit-learn`  requires `numpy` and `scipy`
Thus, before upgrading `scikit-learn` make sure that the compatible version of both `numpy` and `scipy` are installed , and then try to upgrade `scikit-learn`.